# iptables redirect outside requests to 127.0.0.1

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, network-interface

I have a service running on 127.0.0.1 with port 2222. I need to forward all requests to 192.168.2.2:2222 (outside IP) **only from** subnet 192.168.1.0/24 to 127.0.0.1:2222.

I'm trying to use this, but it's not working.

```
$ iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2222
```

How can I get this to work?

UPD: Edit address scheme.

Comment: We need some clarification. Where is the traffic coming from? Where is the traffic originally going to? Where should the traffic be going to? As I read it, you want traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 to 127.0.0.1:2222 to be redirected to 12.23.34.45:2222. But Warren's answer assumes you want traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 to 12.23.34.45:2222 to be redirected to 127.0.0.1:222

Comment: Traffic comes from 192.168.1.0/24 subnet to 192.168.2.2:2222 and should be translated to service on 127.0.0.1:2222. I'm corrected address scheme.

Comment: You want a rule that allows traffic to port `2222` on the loopback interface from subnet `192.168.1.0/24`? That isn't just a single rule type of setup. See here: http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/

Comment: Yes. As I understand I need to add masq rule? IP forwarding is already enabled of course.

Comment: Why not run it on a "real" IP, and filter out traffic comming from unwanted sources? That is what firewalls are for, essentially...

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The iptables rule you are using will work, but there is one additional change you need to make:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

*(replacing `eth0` with the nic `192.168.2.2` resides on)*

By default this value is `0`, which instructs the kernel to not route external traffic destined to `127.0.0.0/8`. This is just for security as such traffic is not normal.

Comment: This info is surprisingly hard to find.

Comment: Yes, very valuable hard-to-find information! Thank you! But I don't have `route_localnet`. Have there been other names for it? (in linux 2.6.30) `ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lan/`: accept_redirects     arp_accept    arp_filter  arp_notify   disable_policy  force_igmp_version  log_martians   medium_id            proxy_arp  secure_redirects  shared_media
accept_source_route  arp_announce  arp_ignore  bootp_relay  disable_xfrm    forwarding          mc_forwarding  promote_secondaries  rp_filter  send_redirects    tag

Comment: I see, [the patch for `route_localnet`](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/163683/) is more recent (June 7, 2012) than my kernel ( 2.6.30-std-def-alt15 #1 SMP Mon Dec 14 08:45:48 UTC 2009). Ok, I'll simply achieve the wanted port-forwarding (from outside to inside) with a forwarding process like `netcat` (`nc`), `xinetd`, or the port-forwarding options of `ssh` (the latter is ineffective and stupid, of course, but I mention it, because, well, this possibility is there).

Comment: My 2 cents: you may enable this parameter for all interfaces with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1`

Comment: Like others, this info was hard to come by.  Thanks, if I'd found this earlier, would have saved me a tonne of effort.

Comment: Thank you very much, surprisingly route_localnet didn't exist by default or commented in `systctl.conf`

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect to localhost but not to loopback (127.0.0.0/8). Loopback is a loophole. You have to redirect to one of your real interfaces. Try using REDIRECT.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ..... -j REDIRECT --to-port 222`

Comment: This is probably the best answer without the sysctl voodo...

Comment: Still doesn't help if port 222 is only being listened on localhost (the rule won't change destination address)

Comment: In that case, use `-j DNAT --to-destination w.x.y.z:222`

Comment: Thanks @dresende, `-j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:<port>` works great!<br/>

This is the full command I used to forward connection to a MariaDB server listening on port 1186:  
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1186 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1186`

Answer (score 5):

What if the correct answer with `route_localnet` doesn't work?..

If your kernel doesn't include [the patch for `route_localnet`](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/163683/), then... upgrade the kernel!

Or there are other ways to forward the traffic coming to one interface to another port on another interface (in particular, to localhost) by running a process that would listen on the external interface and forward the traffic.

`netcat` (`nc`), `xinetd`, and `ssh` (and perhaps more) are all examples of programs able to do this (although choosing `ssh` would be strange and ineffective).

I've written a configuration for `xinetd` for this. Now this service is automatically brought up:

```
# cat /etc/xinetd.d/z-from-outside 
# default: off
# description: Forward connections to the z port.
service z-from-outside
{
    disable         = no
    socket_type     = stream
    type        = UNLISTED
    wait            = no
    user            = nobody
    bind        = vaio.ob
    port        = 7070
    redirect    = localhost 7070
}
#
```

(`vaio.ob` is the name of this host on the external network interface.)

After a `service xinetd reload`, let's check that it is listening:

```
# lsof -i -P | fgrep 7070
xinetd    556      root    6u  IPv4 1797906      0t0  TCP vaio.ob:7070 (LISTEN)
sshd    27438 tun_zzoom    4u  IPv4 1059100      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:7070 (LISTEN)
#
```

And indeed, connections do go through!